# Possible to ignore @TextIndexed on fields with Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have class along the lines of:

```java
public class Person {

  @TextIndexed
  String name;

  List<Person> contacts;

  // getters and setters
  ...
}
```

The `@TextIndexed` allows me to search people by name. However, after I recently added a list of contacts I discovered that their names will also be added to the text index. Is there a way around this other than having a separate class - identical to Person but without the `@TextIndexed` annotations? Perhaps an annotation that will serialize the field but not utilize its indexes?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of such an annotation, but one possible way to go about this would be to use polymorphism. For example, an abstract Person class that is extended by both versions (indexed and non-indexed). Then only annotate the name attribute inside the class where you want it indexed.